# Recording One Second Videos Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am using `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` to record video. I would like to save one second of video, then change the file path and save the next second somewhere else.

Is this possible? Is there some sort of timer I would have to set up? Below is the code in my record function:

```
 let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
 let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/output.mov"
 outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
 output.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL as URL!, recordingDelegate: self)
```

Here is the code in which I set up the output record controller and everything:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.back)

    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)!{
        if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back){

            do{
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                }

               // sessionOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange as UInt32)]

                sessionOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

                if(captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) == true){
                    captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                    let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
                        let preview =  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
                        preview?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
                        preview?.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
                        preview?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
                        return preview!
                    }()

                    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)

                    output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
                    let maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(180, 30)
                    output.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration
                    captureSession.addOutput(output)



                }

                captureSession.commitConfiguration()

            }

            catch{
                print("Error")
            }


        }

    }

    let deviceDiscoverySession2 = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInMicrophone], mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)

    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession2?.devices)!{


        do{
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

            if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                captureSession.addInput(input)

            }



        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        }

        catch{
            print("Error")
        }





}
```

}

Comment: Did you wired up some IBOutlets and removed it later in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` can do what you want. From a comment in the superclass `AVCaptureFileOutput`:

> File outputs can start recording to a new file using the startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate: method. On successive invocations of this method on Mac OS X, the output file can by changed dynamically without losing media samples.

On iOS you'll have to drop back to a combination of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` and `AVAssetWriter`s that you create, start and stop for each segment.

It's not the easiest task. What are you trying to achieve? Could you instead record to a single file then split it into segments in a post-processing phase?

Comment: I'm surprised you accepted the answer - did you requirements change?

Comment: No they didn't, but I think your answer is a basic solution to my question